# How can I unsubscribe f

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have code in my OnAppearing that creates a TableSelection, populates it and adds a Tapped event.

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        RefreshPage();
        TableSection section;
        section = new TableSection("Select from Available Categories");
        foreach (var category in categoryGroups)
        {
           var cell = new CategoryGroupTextCell { BindingContext = category };
           cell.Tapped += openCategoriesPage;
           section.Add(cell);
        }
        tableView.Root.Add(section);
    }
```

It's been mentioned to me that I may need to unsubscribe the events that were added.

Is this the case and if so how should I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `OnDisappearing` method to unsubscribe event-handlers:

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();

    foreach (var section in tableView.Root)
    {
        foreach(var cell in section)
        {
            cell.Tapped -= openCategoriesPage;
        }
    }
}
```